# pushViewController not displaying the new viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9

I am trying to push a viewController on receiving a notification as given below:

```
-(void)pushController:(NSNotification *)notifcation{
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard"; 
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"abc"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
});}
```

I checked the other solutions and double checked that my [self navigationController] is not nil nor is my "vc" nil.I also checked that the push code is running on the main thread. Also I tried displaying the viewControllers inside my navigationController and I see that my "vc" is getting pushed on the navigationController stack but it is just not getting displayed on the screen. Can anyone guide me as to where I could possibly be going wrong.

Comment: Your last line seems weird for me try       `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:false];` and make sure you have a navigationController inside your `UIControllerView`

Comment: Doesn't work :( Checked it. Also if I push any other viewController it works. This one viewController in particular is not displayed. Also it stopped working after the iOS 9 and Xcode 7 upgrade, the same code worked before the upgrade.

Comment: Maybe something is breaking in the storyboard about this viewController. Delete  it and make it again.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what is breaking in the viewController?

Comment: Yes if you have something in the log during the runtime.